# How to configure a WCF service for a load balancer

Tags: wcf

How to configure a WCF service for a load balancer and specific the end points

Comment: Are you doing "normal" load-balancing (i.e. just forwarding requests to different servers), or are you using the load balancer for SSL-offloading?

Answer (score 1):

You could try writing a [custom service host factory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.activation.servicehostfactory.aspx) which will use the load balancer's url as base address:

```
public class CustomServiceHostFactory : ServiceHostFactory
{
    protected override ServiceHost CreateServiceHost(
        Type serviceType, Uri[] baseAddresses)
    {
        Uri uri = null;
        if (baseAddresses.Length < 2)
        {
            uri = baseAddresses[0];
        }
        else
        {
            // TODO: You need to choose the load balancer's url here:
            uri = baseAddresses[????];
        }
        return base.CreateServiceHost(serviceType, new Uri[] { uri });
    }
}
```